# Declare character of size 2 bytes in c under linux

Tags: c, linux, unicode

I am studying about unicode support. I am working on linux. I know there is build-in datatype wchar_t in c which declares character of size 4 bytes under linux. But what is way to declare character of byte 2? C++11 introduces char16_t to declare character with size 2 byte, is there no build in datatype in c to achieve this?

Comment: C11 have both `char16_t` and `char32_t` as well. They are defined in the `<uchar.h>` header. (See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte).)

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg yes i know c11 has char32_t also but my question is what is equivalent datatype in c of char16_t in c++.

Comment: The equivalent of the C++ `char16_t` type in C is `char16_t`.

Comment: What's wrong with `uint16_t` from `stdint.h` ?

Answer (score 0):

yes you have

> wchar_t

you can use `#include < wchar.h>`

Comment: OP already knows this and says that it is 4 bytes on linux and so not very useful in solving the problem of 2 byte size requirement

Answer (score -2):

You can use a short which is 16 bits(2 bytes) by the following-

```
short x;
```

But, there is a catch. It is only for numbers.

Another example-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    short x = 0;
    printf("X is %d\n", x + 1);
}
```

Comment: You claim `short` has always 16 bits. That is not true.

Comment: I know but on most MODERN systems it is indeed 16 bits.